# delete a row in csv file

Tags: java, opencsv

I am appending the data to the last row of a csv. I wanted to delete the existing row and then rewrite it with the appended element. Is there any way of deleting the row in csv? I am using opencsv to read and the write the file. I tried using CSVIterator class. However, it seems the iterator does not support the remove() operation. 
Here is the code that I tried:

```
static String[] readLastRecord(File outputCSVFile) throws WAGException {
        checkArgument(outputCSVFile != null, "Output CSV file cannot be null");
        FileReader fileReader = null;
        CSVReader csvFileReader = null;
        CSVIterator csvIterator = null;
        String[] csvLastRecord = null;
        try {
            fileReader = new FileReader(outputCSVFile);
            csvFileReader = new CSVReader(fileReader, ',', '\'',
                    csvRowCount - 1);
            csvIterator = new CSVIterator(csvFileReader);
            while (csvIterator.hasNext()) {
                csvLastRecord = csvIterator.next();
                csvIterator.remove();
            }
        } catch (IOException ioEx) {
            throw new WAGException(
                    WAGInputExceptionMessage.FILE_READ_ERR.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (csvFileReader != null)
                    csvFileReader.close();
            } catch (IOException ioEx) {
                throw new WAGException(
                        WAGInputExceptionMessage.FILE_CLOSE_ERR.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return csvLastRecord;
    }
```

Comment: The API says that `remove()` *is* supported by iterator: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/  when you write "it seems the iterator does not support the remove() operation" - you should provide more details: it doesn't compile ? it compiles but doesn't run ? it runs but doesn't do what you want it to do ?

Comment: The implementation on the sourceforge.net says its not supported.. It is a read-only iterator. http://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/source/ci/3ba1873ef55b014893cae73b015d2bcb55b7d5a4/tree/src/main/java/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVIterator.java

Comment: In that case - you'll have to read all the lines into a data-structure (List might be good enough), remove the line you want and override (re-write) the file.

Answer (score 7):

i just found an answer. Hope it helps.

You need to read the csv, add elements to the **list string**, remove specific row from it with **allelements.remove(rowNumber)** and then write the list string back to the csv file.

The rowNumber is an **int** with row number.

```
CSVReader reader2 = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filelocation));
List<String[]> allElements = reader2.readAll();
allElements.remove(rowNumber);
FileWriter sw = new FileWriter(filelocation);
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(sw);
writer.writeAll(allElements);
writer.close();
```

Look at this example from opencsv [opencsv example](https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/source/ci/master/tree/examples/AddressExample.java)

Answer (score 0):

use unset to remove the row in csv

```
function readCSV($csvFile){
   $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
   while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
      $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
   }
   fclose($file_handle);
   return $line_of_text;
}

$csvFile1 = '../build/js/snowcem.csv';
$csv1 = readCSV($csvFile1); 
//specified row number want to delete on place of $id
unset($csv1[$id]);
$file = fopen("../build/js/snowcem.csv","w");

foreach ($csv1 as $file1) {
    $result = [];
    array_walk_recursive($file1, function($item) use (&$result) {
    $item = '"'.$item.'"';
        $result[] = $item;
    });
    fputcsv($file, $result);
}

fclose($file);
```

Comment: OP is looking for Java-specific answers as the [tag:java] tag is present.